# systemd journal - delete logs belonging to a specified unit?

Tags: rsyslog, journald

Like there is a way to show all logs belonging to a unit: `journalctl -xu <unit>`,
Is there a way to clear the logs belonging to a specified unit with `journalctl` ?

Actually, my problem is, one of the service which is imported (from Sys-V `/etc/init.d` file automatically by `systemd`) is logging and that is seen in both `syslog` as well as `journal`!

I want to remove the logs from the `journal` as it eats up a lot of space! From the manuals,
there is no way to tell `journald` to NOT persist certain logs! I don't want to forward *all*
logs to `syslog` ! So, I am thinking, if I could periodically *remove* the said unit's logs
from `journal`, it will be a huge win!

Comment: As i wouldn't disable journald altogether, it's possible to define a "max storage". E.g. Add `SystemMaxUse=100M` to `/etc/systemd/journald.conf` to only keep the last 100MB of all journald logs.

Comment: maxstorage will only restrict the amount of space taken by journal logs! I searched high and low, there seems to be no option to clear specific logs!

Comment: Ohh i see.. My bad, I didn't read it correct. AFAIK you can't "tell" journald what it should/shouldn't log or that only specific logs should be persistent. You'd have to write a script to achieve what you want.